# How to know if photo in Landscape or Portrait mode?

Tags: iphone, ipad, photo

I load photo from iPhone/iPad library, most of them in Portrait mode, I want to know How can I check the photo in Landscape or Portrait mode?

Comment: do you want to know the orientation of the device or of the photo? You can get the current device orientation with Viren's answer. Otherwise, compare the height and width of the photo get its aspect ratio. But there would be no way to know the actual orientation.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `imageOrientation` property of `UIImage` instances. It is going to return you one of [these](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIImageOrientation) constants.

Example:

UIImage *image = // loaded from library

```
if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
    NSLog(@"portrait");
} else if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    NSLog(@"landscape");
}
```

Comment: This helped me get started with album selection and I want to add some supplemental info for photo taking, which I didn't realize were 2 totally different things! When a user takes a snapshot with the iPhone’s camera, the image is not upright but is in fact rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise. So if you wanted to end up in the `if` block for `NSLog(@"portrait");` then you would test for `UIImageOrientationLeft || UIImageOrientationRight || UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored || UIImageOrientationRightMirrored` and the rest will be `landscape`

Answer (score 1):

I tested this piece of code on tens of actual picture on iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0 and was able to successfully make them all in portrait mode. This is how you fix/check

```
if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp ||
        image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown )
    {
        NSLog(@"Image is in Landscape Fix it to portrait ....");

        backgroundView.frame = self.view.bounds;
        backgroundView.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        backgroundView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Image is in Portrait everything is fine ...");
    }
```

Here is a fool proof way of doing this check

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    // Get the data for the image
    NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);




    if ([UIImage imageWithData:imageData].size.width >  [UIImage imageWithData:imageData].size.height)
    {
        NSLog(@"Select Image is in Landscape Mode ....");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Select Image is in Portrait Mode ...");

    }
}
```